# How to determine if an equation is algebraically solvable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

**Problem**

I was given the following equation to solve for $x$:

$$35x^{9 / 5} + 180x^{7 / 5} + 252x = 50400 / \pi$$

But don't get hung up on it. It's only an example.

**My solution**

...was simply to use a calculator, which gave me a seemingly irrational number, which is understandable given the presence of pi.

But at the same time, I was wondering if this equation was solvable by typical algebraic methods, like substitutions yielding a quadratic equation for example.

But more generally, I started wondering how I could determine whether or not it is solvable algebraically.

**Question**

Do we have any "if such-and-such is not satisfied, go numerical" rules of thumb? Or do we just make a judgment call?

Comment: do you want to solve it for $x$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - Yes. But as I mentioned soon after, I'm not looking to find the answer to the equation. It's just an example :)

Comment: Always go numerical.

Comment: Numerical methods seems to be the only choice.

Answer (score 1):

Using $y = x^{1/5}$ we get
\begin{align}
50400 / \pi 
&= 35 \, x^{9 / 5} + 180 \, x^{7 / 5} + 252 \, x \\
&= 35 \, y^9 + 180 \, y^7 + 252 \, y^5 \\
\end{align}
Thus we are looking for the roots of
$$
f(x) = 35 y^9 + 180 y^7 + 252 y^5 - 50400/\pi
$$
which is a polynomial of degree $d=9$. Unfortunately Abel and Galois showed that in general there is no algebraic method available for $d > 4$, so go numeric!

For speed one would use the Newton-Raphson iteration, but it is also fun to look for a fixed point instead.
$$
F(x) 
= \frac{50400/\pi - 35 y^9 - 180 y^7}{252 y^4}
= \frac{50400/\pi}{252 y^4} - \frac{35}{252} y^5 - \frac{180}{252} y^3
$$

Comment: So $x^5-1=0$ doesn't have a closed form solution because it has degree 5?

Comment: In general means that there are cases which will not work. Abel pulled out the first such quintic.

Comment: It seems to have been $x^5 - x + 1$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: I know that. What I tried to say is that just because a polynomial is of degree $> 4$ doesn't mean it isn't algebraically solvable, only that there is no general solution for all polynomials of that degree.

Comment: That is why added "in general". I also had a footnote and five skulls  saying do not take this too pessimistic, but dropped that because I thought "in general" would be good enough. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Application_to_classical_problems) tells you all about how to determine if you can solve the polynomial.  I'm not too familiar with the subject, but the first few paragraphs in the link provided should answer the question "Is there a way to determine if some equation is algebraically solvable?", but I can not answer the "how".